# Katalon with GitLab CI, katalon is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ui-automation, gitlab-ci, katalon-studio

I am trying to setup a simple TESTSUITE with katalon to run automatically on Gitlab but I keep hitting this error :

katalon is not recognized as an internal or external command when i run this script:

I have followed this tutorial. And tried using katalon-execute.sh instead of katalon but no changes

https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/continuous_integration_gitlab.html#add-katalon-path-to-environment-variables

Some help would be really appreciated.

run_katalon_test_suite:
      tags:
        - shell
      script:

```
        katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -projectPath=
      "My project path>" -retry=0
      -testSuitePath="Test Suites/FirstTestSuite>" -executionProfile=
      "default" -browserType="Chrome (headless)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to navigate to the folder where Katalon is installed and then run the console command from that folder.

Comment: Now it tells me that git is not recognized !






variables:
  PATH: "C:\\Program Files\\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-6.1.4"
run_katalon_test_suite:
      tags:
        - shell
      script:
        
            katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -projectPath=
          "C:\Users\lkrasniqi\Desktop\huberlabTEST\huberlab1\huberlabtest\huberlab1.prj>" -retry=0
          -testSuitePath="Test Suites/FirstTestSuite>" -executionProfile=
          "default" -browserType="Chrome (headless)"

Comment: So, `katalon.exe` is in the `C:\\Program Files\\Katalon_Studio_Windows_64-6.1.4` folder? What message about git not recognized are you getting?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nowt82 check this img to have a better understanding of the error

Comment: Not sure about that error, because I'm not using Gitlab from cmd. But the principle is the same. Your shell script is looking for git.exe and it is not finding it because it is in another folder.

Answer (score 1):

If it is shell script then it should start with **./**
The solution will need a change in the shell script.

```
./katalon -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -projectPath=
  "My project path>" -retry=0
  -testSuitePath="Test Suites/FirstTestSuite>" -executionProfile=
  "default" -browserType="Chrome (headless)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say if u katalon IDE is located in ur Desktop

```
"C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Katalon_windows/Katalon.exe" -noSplash  -runMode=console -consoleLog -projectPath="My project path>" -retry=0 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/FirstTestSuite>" -executionProfile= "default" -browserType="Chrome (headless)"
```